# When was "goodbye" in its most modern form first used?

Tags: etymology

I've seen when the word transitioned from *Godbwye* to *goodbwye*, but when did it become *goodbye*?

Comment: The 1590s - http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=goodbye&searchmode=none

Answer (score 1):

According to [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=goodbye&searchmode=none) (cited by Jim above), it is originally derived from *God be with ye* in the late 14th century.